# PayPal authorized payments Capture

Tags: java, spring-boot, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to integrate paypal in my spring boot app using the pay pal SDK.I configured authorize payments its working fine but when Iam trying to capture the authorize payments I have to pass authorization Id as the paypal document mentioned but I'm unable set authorization ID since document not clearly showing which attribute or object to set it.

How can I set the authorization ID and execute the capture request?

Please refer "Capture authorization" in below link
Document link -https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/quickstart/capture-payment/#capture-authorization

Comment: The docs aren't very clear, but I'm wondering if it's in the apiContext object

Comment: No. apiContext is for add client secret and client ID